# Losing vowel mutations in Powershell type convertion

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365, exchange-server

So I have an outlook signature template file (.htm) if I want to add the signature to O365 via powershell with:
`Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration -signatureHTML <STRING>`

`-signatureHTML` expects a string, but if I use `-signature HTML (Get-Content -Path C:\mysignature.htm)` it doesn't work because the Datatype returned of Get-Content is an Array (`GetType()` confirmed that for me)

It WORKS if I declare a new variable `[string]$htmcontent = (Get-Content -Path C:\mysignature.htm)` BUT here comes my problem:
In Germany we use ÜÄÖ,öäü or ß, after converting the htm-file into the string-datatype an "Ä" becomes a "Ã¼" and so on.

Any idea how I can fix that? Appreciate your help!

See above, explained it there.

Comment: [`Get-Content -Raw -Encoding <encoding>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content#-encoding)?

Comment: Good idea, thanks, that way i dont need [string], but the encoding-errors still persist and "Ä" is shown as "Ã¼"

Comment: Well if i only I read a little further in the microsoft docs xd, thank you very much! That did the trick!

Comment: What is **shown** depends on your terminal and doesn't have to be the same as what is actual used, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/1701026

Comment: I've checked in outlook webapp where i saw the encoding error, after adding "-encoding UTF8" it worked perfectly fine, no encoding errors in the signature!

Comment: @LukasFritzsche, if you found a solution, feel free to write up an answer to your question.

Comment: Utf8 files need a BOM for powershell 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`Get-Content -Raw -Encoding UTF8`
```

Did the trick and it works perfectly fine!
Thank you very much iRon!